# Reducing transfer time between Mars and Saturn

Tags: delta-v, hohmann-transfer, transfer-time

How would I estimate the transfer time between Mars and Saturn if I have more Delta-V than necessary for a Hohmann transfer?

Comment: Lambert's problem may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem

Answer (score 3):

I whomped up [a spreadsheet](http://clowder.net/hop/TMI/NonHohmannMarsToSaturn.xlsx) where you can set perihelion and aphelion of transfer orbit.

Here's a screen capture from the spreadsheet where I set perihelion of transfer orbit at 1 A.U. and aphelion at 12 A.U.

[image]

Of course SMA is (perihelion+aphelion)/2. Where the transfer orbit crosses Mars orbit, r is 1.524 A.U.. At Saturn, r is 9.537 A.U.. Knowing a, mu and r you can figure speed using the [vis viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation).

Besides speeds you must also take angle between velocity vectors into account. Incorrectly assuming Mars and Saturn are in circular orbits, that angle would be transfer orbit's [flight path angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_orbit#Flight_path_angle). Then you can use the law of cosines to get the delta V between vectors.

I am hoping you will examine the cells in this spreadsheet and try to reverse engineer what I did.

Here's a screen capture with some of the relevant numbers emphasized:

[image]

You would do well to proofread this spreadsheet. I hastily adapted it from a NonHohmann Earth To Mars spreadsheet. I tried to relabel and replace different quantities like planet radius, gravitational parameter, and so on. But I do make mistakes. I would be grateful if anyone reviewed my efforts.